# SVG Image neither displayed by IMG nor Background Image

Tags: html, css, svg

I can't get the SVG Image to disaply correctly in Google Chrome 34

[Example](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-sprites/sprite.html)

As you can see object and iframes are working. IMG and Backgroudn image aren't working.

IE11 and FireFox can display all 4 examples correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Chrome developers [have chosen not to support the use of SVG fragments in images](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128055) in order to protect user's privacy.

Because your SVG file only displays each shape if it is the target of a URL fragment (the part after `#` in the filename), nothing is displayed when Chrome strips out the fragment.

Comment: (Hope you don't mind the edits.  Nowhere in the question or original answer text was there an explanation of the key fact that this involved fragment targets.)